# Cannot retrieve images in my react component

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack, urlloader

I am quite new at coding so please be indulgent... I searched a lot and I don't manage to get my issue fixed :(

I would like to get my images rendered through and html img tag. I saw that the best way in react is to import my images. Like this :

```
import avatar from './avatar.png';

export default class Connection extends React.Component {
  render () {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.user.firstname}&nbsp;{this.props.user.lastname}
          &nbsp;<img src={avatar} className='img-circle' />
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' onClick={this.props.logout}>Déconnexion</a>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

I use the following webpack config to load these images :

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: [/node_modules/], loader: 'babel' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader') },
      { test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g|svg|jpg)$/i, loader: 'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[path][name]-[hash].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g|svg|jpg)$/i, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000' }
    ]
  }
```

I see that webpack manage to load the jpg or png files but when it comes to display it, it seems that the file generated/copied is not available (ex: /MyApp/avatar-50b93a2df8aec266d7c8c1c0f5719d1b.png is not available).

I use the webpack dev server so I don't see my files bundled and the dist or build folder created.

Any idea of solving my issue ?

Thanks,

When using the require within the img tag I get the following error :

Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./avatar

I tried to get the extension in the webpack config but it does not solve anything :(

Here is my public path config in my webpack config :

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
```

Comment: What publicPath have you set in webpack config file?

Comment: Just added the info :)

Comment: Try running you dev server by adding '--content-base build/' in your dev server run command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load images with Webpack you need to do:

```
<img src={require('./avatar.jpg'})/>
```

Webpack crawls through your application codebase, code gets bundled into a single file however files are not kept in the same structure, by calling `require` Webpack will do dependency management for you, in this case the file will move around and code will be injected so it is pointing to it's bundled location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but by doing what you say I get the error described above

Comment: Forgot to add file extension in there, try with that and let me know how it goes

Comment: There is no need of require as import works the same way.

Comment: With the resolve info for png or jpg extension (my file is a png) it does not manage to get the file displayed even if it manages to solve the file type

Comment: @prakash also tried and it says cannot find module '..../avatar-50b93a2df8aec266d7c8c1c0f5719d1b.png'

Comment: @ClementLevesque try to add this to your webpack config: {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'file'
      },

Comment: Finally the way to solve my problem was to use the url-loader without the file-loader which includes it. I did not know about that but it seems that it was the issue :) thanks a lot for your help anyway ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this article from SurviveJS Book. [Load Images Chapter](http://survivejs.com/webpack/understanding-loaders/loading-images/)
[image: Extract from SurviveJS]